# Flutter file picker - can't copy cached to permanent location "No such file or directory"

Tags: flutter, caching, filepicker

I am having the same problem trying with 2 different libraries: 'file_picker' and 'file_picker_cross', the 2nd one is based on the first but adds a 'save to path' method. Either way when I try so save the cached file to a new location it says the file is not there but the log shows the same path when the cached is created.
This is the debug console:

> D/FilePickerUtils( 6944): **File loaded and cached at:/data/user/0/com.example.app/cache/file_picker/bielsa.epub**
> D/FilePickerDelegate( 6944): File path:[com.mr.flutter.plugin.filepicker.FileInfo@e35c1fa]
> E/flutter ( 6944): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(198)] Unhandled Exception: FileSystemException: Cannot copy file to '/data/user/0/com.example.app/app_flutter/4aZJ7NQ/9789500737494.epub', path = **'/data/user/0/com.example.app/cache/file_picker/bielsa.epub'** (OS Error: No such file or directory, errno = 2)

And here is my code:

```
onPressed: () async {
        FilePickerCross myFile = await FilePickerCross.importFromStorage(
            type: FileTypeCross
                .custom, 
            fileExtension:
                'epub'
            );
        final appstorage = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
        String path =
            '${appstorage.path}/$myUser/${bookInfo.isbn13}.${myFile.fileExtension}';
        await myFile.saveToPath(path: path);

        var newfile = File(myFile.path!).copy(path);}
```

The last 2 lines do the same, so should be one or the other but both run into the same problem.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: most likely you don't have write access to `/data/user/0/com.example.app/app_flutter/4aZJ7NQ/` do you run it on Android?

Comment: Yes Android, how can I add or request those permissions?

Comment: what do you see if you run `adb shell ls -ld /data/user/0/com.example.app/app_flutter/4aZJ7NQ`?

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I didn't have ADB. It just says 'Permission denied'.

Comment: drwxrwx--x : these until /data/user/0/, denied when I add the domain

Answer (score 0):

In this case in particular the error is caused because the path given to write the new file includes a folder that does not exist.

String path = '${appstorage.path}/***$myUser/***${bookInfo.isbn13}.${myFile.fileExtension}';

The subfolder /$myUser it is not created automatically to store the file, it must be created before hand or removed from the path and the file will be copied correctly.